# facebook sdk request dialog 'cancel' button issues different callback on iOS & Android

Tags: facebook, button, dialog, request

[image] [image]

At this moment, when clicking 'Cancel' button(not native 'x' image button) on upper left side of facebook Request Dialog, it redirects to below URL.

```
fbconnect://success?error_code=4201&error_message=User+canceled+the+Dialog+flow
```

And, **it causes to issue different callbacks on iOS and Android, namely, an error callback on Android, and a success callback on iOS.**

And it's clear when looking at corresponding SDK source code. Corresponding [facebook android sdk source code(3.8)](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/widget/WebDialog.java#L360-403) looks like :

```
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Utility.logd(LOG_TAG, "Redirect URL: " + url);
        if (url.startsWith(WebDialog.REDIRECT_URI)) { // "WebDialog.REDIRECT_URI" is "fbconnect://success"
            Bundle values = Util.parseUrl(url); // "values" is Bundle[{error_message=User canceled the Dialog flow, error_code=4201}]

            String error = values.getString("error");
            if (error == null) {
                error = values.getString("error_type");
            }

            String errorMessage = values.getString("error_msg");
            if (errorMessage == null) {
                errorMessage = values.getString("error_description");
            }
            String errorCodeString = values.getString("error_code");
            int errorCode = FacebookRequestError.INVALID_ERROR_CODE; // FacebookRequestError.INVALID_ERROR_CODE is -1
            if (!Utility.isNullOrEmpty(errorCodeString)) {
                try {
                    errorCode = Integer.parseInt(errorCodeString);
                } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                    errorCode = FacebookRequestError.INVALID_ERROR_CODE;
                }
            }

            // At this point, 'error' is null,  'errorMessage' is null,
            // but errorCode is 4201. So, it goes to 'else' branch.
            if (Utility.isNullOrEmpty(error) && Utility
                    .isNullOrEmpty(errorMessage) && errorCode == FacebookRequestError.INVALID_ERROR_CODE) {
                sendSuccessToListener(values);
            } else if (error != null && (error.equals("access_denied") ||
                    error.equals("OAuthAccessDeniedException"))) {
                sendCancelToListener();
            } else {
                FacebookRequestError requestError = new FacebookRequestError(errorCode, error, errorMessage);
                sendErrorToListener(new FacebookServiceException(requestError, errorMessage));
            }

            WebDialog.this.dismiss();
            return true;
        } else if (url.startsWith(WebDialog.CANCEL_URI)) {
            sendCancelToListener();
            WebDialog.this.dismiss();
            return true;
        } else if (url.contains(DISPLAY_TOUCH)) {
            return false;
        }
        // launch non-dialog URLs in a full browser
        getContext().startActivity(
                new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
        return true;
    }
```

So,it calls `sendErrorToListener`. On the other hand, [corresponding iOS SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/src/Legacy/FBDialog.m#L446-484) looks like :

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
NSURL *url = request.URL;

if ([url.scheme isEqualToString:@"fbconnect"]) {
    if ([[url.resourceSpecifier substringToIndex:8] isEqualToString:@"//cancel"]) {
        NSString *errorCode = [self getStringFromUrl:[url absoluteString] needle:@"error_code="];
        NSString *errorStr = [self getStringFromUrl:[url absoluteString] needle:@"error_msg="];
        if (errorCode) {
            NSDictionary *errorData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:errorStr forKey:@"error_msg"];
            NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"facebookErrDomain"
                                                 code:[errorCode intValue]
                                             userInfo:errorData];
            [self dismissWithError:error animated:YES];
        } else {
            [self dialogDidCancel:url];
        }
    } else {
        if (_frictionlessSettings.enabled) {
            [self dialogSuccessHandleFrictionlessResponses:url];
        }
        [self dialogDidSucceed:url];
    }
    return NO;
} else if ([_loadingURL isEqual:url]) {
    return YES;
} else if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(dialog:shouldOpenURLInExternalBrowser:)]) {
        if (![_delegate dialog:self shouldOpenURLInExternalBrowser:url]) {
            return NO;
        }
    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:request.URL];
    return NO;
} else {
    return YES;
}
```

}

So it calls `dialogDidSucceed` routine.

I think it should call the same callback on both platform for consistency. Why don't they redirect to `fbconnect://cancel` rather than `fbconnect://success` on being canceled. Am I missing something? Or it's just a temporal mistake by facebook team?